# Is there an easy way to get started with basscss?

Tags: css

I am trying out the different **basscss** examples. But often there are selectors that are not present in the css files I have - so I am installing more, which is time consuming, and becoming confusing. Is there an example html file somewhere that contains them all? Here is the [getting started guide](http://www.basscss.com/v7/docs/), which isn't really helpful in this respect.

I started off with `css/basscss.css`, but then found out I needed `css/colors.css`, and so on. As I kept going I started to suspect there were overlaps. I haven't found any file (even the `min` one) that has everything in it.

I wouldn't mind installing them all separately if there was some kind of a guide - even just an `index.html` with css links that would make all the examples work straight away would be great.

Comment: The [CDN link](https://npmcdn.com/basscss@7.1.1/css/basscss.min.css) on the getting started page seems to have everything included, no?

Comment: I started with that link but at 8.0.1 (that link is for 7.1.1). Will try again now - good advice - 7.1.1 does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing BASSCSS through bower but package seems to be broken. And I went over the documentation and source code. So I referenced the CDN as SteveAx suggested and that's a good start. Now if you wanted to use the UI Elements (buttons, navbars, etc.) of BASSCSS there's a note that states "Note: this guide makes use of the optional UI Utility Groups module that is not included in the default Basscss package."

Here's a link to that Utility Group: https://www.npmjs.com/package/basscss-ui-utility-groups

I would think of BASSCSS to be similar to Bootstrap or Foundation, if you were hoping to use more lightweight styling framework maybe check out http://getskeleton.com/ or http://purecss.io/ which include most of the UI elements that BASSCSS has as optional.

Comment: I've looked at skeleton. Seems I'm trying them all out. My use case is that I'm coding in ClojureScript and don't want to include JavaScript, so looking for css that I can compose components from. Happy for it to only work with modern browsers.

Comment: I don't need anything that is particularly lightweight (not aiming for mobile). Something well designed, well documented, easy to get going, plenty of examples..

Comment: I downloaded basscss-ui-utility-groups using npm. It just has an index.css with like 10 lines of css. Am I supposed to rename and link to it from my html? Its all a bit confusing.

Comment: Hi Chris, you're right the index.css only having 10 lines. I scoured basscss repositories and found this basscss addons: https://github.com/basscss/addons. Depending on what addon module you want to use like "forms", "btn", "colors". Just run the command "npm i -D basscss- ", for example if you want to install buttons "npm i -D basscss-btn". That will install the necessary css files a folder in the "node_modules" folder you can reference in your html.

Comment: So much non-nonsensical work for us users. I'm investigating your **purecss** recommendation at the moment - certainly its 'Getting Started' guide is brilliant in comparison - all of which doesn't rule out **basscss** being a *hidden gem*.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I think my answer will help a lot of people who want to use all css addons and everything provided by basscss with just one line of code:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ace-css/css/ace.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Simply enter this line of code in your  tags and everything basscss offers plus much more will be available in your web page :)